# how to transfer files from SE 30 to usb device

Tags: mac, usb, data-transfer

I inherited a working SE 30 Macintosh, how can I transfer the Word 5 files to a USB device?

Comment: Do you have a network connection?  Do you know how to make/obtain a null modem (serial) cable and are familiar with transfer protocols like kermit, xmodem or zmodem?  Can you get a USB floppy drive and some 3.5” disks?

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough I actually **have** a working SE/30.

I have found the easiest way to transfer files (well... files under 1.4MB) is via floppy disk.

The SE/30 has a floppy built in and you can get external USB drives for Macs online. I seem to recall they were pretty cheap.

Thought you are limited to a file size that will fit on a floppy. I believe Stuffit is still around and could potentially split larger files into smaller files. The exercise in getting a copy of Stuffit compatible with (and onto the SE/30, likely via floppy) is left up to you ;-)

Also the SE/30 has an expansion slot, so you could, theoretically, buy a used SE/30 ethernet card off eBay (or wherever) and attempt to use AppleTalk between the (really old) Mac and the (much newer) Mac. Having never actually tried that I am unsure if that would work. EG do newer Macs still support legacy AppleTalk file sharing? not sure I know. But depending on how motivated you are it might be an interesting exercise that we would all love to hear about, once you have a workable solution.

Comment: You have Stuffit from that early? I'm surprised. I thought it came later. Compact Pro was compression king in '90 - https://www.macintoshrepository.org/2024-compact-pro [of course, for either, you're going to need floppy disk sneakernet to get it on the Mac… & ironically, the CP downloads are stuffit-compressed ;)

Comment: Disks are probably the easiest/cheapest solution that doesn’t require too much tech skills.  Null modem is cheapest but the skill requirement is much higher.  Networking is the most robust but has the highest cost both acquisition and implementation wise.

Comment: I did actually find some SCSI > SD adapters for these [not cheap] - meant to run the OS from the SD itself. I guess an SD is probably faster than the original HD;)

Comment: *If I recall correctly* Stuffit was available for system 7. I've got 7.1 on the SE/30. And a lot of the stuffit archives I've found online are self extracting, making installing Compact Pro via a Stuffit archive only a *little* more understandable.

Comment: Yeah, memory is dim - it's 30 years since I last saw an SE30. First Mac I ever had. I think I had an LC & a Quadra over the next couple of years… after that it gets hazy again until G3 & G4s by the end of the 90s.